# How to force 24 bit color depth in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to load and display a texture in OpenGL ES. The problem I am having is that even though my image is in ARGB_8888 format, the texture seems to be drawn in RGB_565 format. Without dithering, my image looks pretty terrible.

I am running my program on a phone which supports 16m colors, therefore, the texture should be view-able in all it's original glory.

**EDIT** code:

loading bitmap:

```
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, null);
```

generating texture:

```
public void loadBackground(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);     
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, background,0);
    background.recycle();
}
```

drawing:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, backgroundVertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,4);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

onSurfaceCreated:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {   
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);         
}
```

onSurfaceChanged

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
```

Comment: ARGB_8888 is a 32-bit format, as it's name suggests: 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 = 32!

Comment: Yup you are right. My image is still being rendered at a lower color depth though

Comment: Can you provide your OpenGL setup code, as well as the code used to load the textures?

Comment: of course, posted it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `GLSurfaceView` is using RGB_565 for its pixel format, so you need to specify that you want a 32 bit surface before you bind the renderer. More info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html , look at one of the `setEGLConfigChooser` methods.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Any idea what would happen If I changed it to RGBA_8888 format but the device could not support that many colors? It seems strange to me that this is the default

Comment: RGB_565 is chosen for performance reasons: reducing everything by two is a huge gain when the main bottleneck is the bandwidth. For what I do, I am happy with RGB_565 being the default. 

I'm not sure what happens if you use more bits than available, but either you get the _closest_ available config or it crashes miserably. Well I guess you could just try now by requesting 32 bits per channel and look at the results.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think I will also stick with RGB_565 in light of this. If I get time, I will try it out though :)